# Install all modules at once in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

How to install all modules in OpenERP at once? At single click it install all modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Pinakin,

Their can be may ways that you can prefer rather being ironic, You have one option as Heroic or you can also use some external shell script which will one go run.

The code can look like this. Save this is Shell script under server folder.

```
#line to drop some existing db if we have any, You can skip this.
psql -l | grep somedb_name |cut -d \| -f1  | xargs -n1 dropdb

# Create new Db
createdb somedb_name --encoding=Unicode

# install base module. and Stop the server
./openerp-server --addons-path=../../addons/trunk,../../web/trunk/addons/ -d somedb_name --stop-after-init -i base



#Now trigger sql and marke all module to install with demo true.
psql somedb_name -c "UPDATE ir_module_module SET state = 'to install', demo = true ;"

#againstart Server and let all module get insalled and then server will keep running foreve you want.
./openerp-server --addons-path=../../addons/trunk,../../web/trunk/addons/ -u base -d somedb_name
```

You may Need to chage the some path depending on your code managment on dir.

Answer (score 6):

If you use a 7.0 then a good news for you.

-> Go to setting ,click on  modules and go to list view of modules.

->Search module that are Not Installed by click on search box.

->click on limit on top right (1-80 of 156) and select unlimited.

->check top left check box that can check all the check box of all module in list view.

-> Now click on more button and then click Module Immediate installed.

-> be Patience this will take some time to installed all module but it surly installed all modules.

Answer (score 1):

While starting the server you can add parameter in the server path like

```
./openerp-server --addons ../addons/,
                  ../openerp-web/addons/ -i <list of modules> -d <database name>
```

give list of module name separated by comma, it will install in the module in the given database.

Comment: Install all modules by commands is easy & time saving rather than creating a module.

Comment: @Atul Makwana: This is shit crab. pleas give me 200 module comma Spepreates list, I will be really please with it.

Comment: @firebug: Its a one time configuration. If you want to install 200 modules then you have to give then as a list. If you have any other solution please show as also

Comment: @OmaL: It seems you not doing development In OpenERP, Answer me how many times we need create new db a day. Well any way You are being Ironic.

Comment: @firebug: Once you install all the modules, take a backup. use this back up to create new one.

Comment: @OmaL: Would like to know after many of XML Chnages, If i wanna see my effect, Backup will do job for me !! Am i am little bit amazed by you here. Again beinf orinic. If I wanna test All YAML kind of situation.
Anyway I do agree with your solution If only you want for once, But while working this is not fact.

Comment: In this case I will create new custom module with all the customization and install it in the restored backup db. If I want to test all yaml, I will update the base.

Comment: @firebug: you can make a method to get all the module name at once
I had made a method to list comma separated module names.
follow the [Blog link](http://atulone.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-install-all-modules-at-once-in.html), its dam easy.

Comment: @AtulMakwana: Certaily But you just being Donky Programmer that judt do nt uderstand the power of the Unix Programming, Anyway, Nice try to  catch me ove your blog. Anyway Besy of Luck.